# Wireguard Multiline Config Value

Tags: wireguard

Is it possible to split a config command over multiple lines instead of one long string?

E.g.

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

When using more commands the line gets very long and unreadable. I would like to split it so that I can use one line per command. Something like:

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; \
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

The man page says it's based on the ini format but has no help on this topic.

Comment: try it and see.  did it work? you have your answer.  did it not work? you also have your answer.

Comment: @cas your answer does not make sense. My example was to show what I am looking for. If I knew the correct format I would not have asked.

Comment: @A.B are you implying it works for you? It's a made up example. No it does not work for me.

Comment: @A.B I really thought that was clear. I'll keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `wg-quick` command is a [bash script](https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/tree/src/wg-quick/linux.bash?h=v1.0.20210424). The loop reading keys (such as the `PostUp` key) is using `read -r` which prevents any use of `\`
to separate lines. But reading this same script shows:

> ```
> POST_UP=( )
> ```

to declare it as an array, and:

> ```
>           PostUp) POST_UP+=( "$value" ); continue ;;
> ```

to add an element to the array.

It's then executed later with (there's an `eval` command in the function `execute_hooks`):

> ```
> execute_hooks "${POST_UP[@]}"
> ```

Thus one can split *multiple commands* (but not *arbitrary lines*) by using multiple times the same key entry. So OP's  example would work like this:

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Actually the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/wireguard-tools/wg-quick.8) already tells it:

> • PreUp, PostUp, PreDown, PostDown — script snippets which will be
> executed by bash(1) before/after setting up/tearing down the
> interface, most commonly used to configure custom DNS options or
> firewall rules. The special string `%i' is expanded to *INTERFACE*.
> **Each one may be specified multiple times, in which case the commands are executed in order**.